# Sequence Diagram into Java Codes : How to?

Tags: java, sequence-diagram

Goodday everyone. I'm actually having some trouble with these Sequence Diagrams.  It says that " All animals live in their own cage depending on the race. " I really need a help with this simple diagram because i really dont know how to write it in my Java program.  im sure its simple for most of yall. So please help me! **here is the Diagram :**

[image]

Zookeeper class / Mainclass :

```
package General;

import Zoo.Cage;

public class ZooKeeper {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Cage cage1 =  new Cage();
   }
}
```

Cage class :

```
public class Cage {
    private String type;
    private ArrayList<Animal> cagedAnimals;

    public Cage(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }  

    public Cage() {
    }

    public Animal selectAnimal(){
        return null;
    }

    public void getCageType(){
    }

    public boolean addAnimal(Animal anAnimal){
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Animal> getCagedAnimals(){
        ArrayList<Animal> i = new ArrayList<>();
        return i;
    }

    public void addReptileEggs(ArrayList<Egg> reptileEggs){
    }
}
```

Zoo class :

```
package Zoo;

import General.Animal;
import General.Egg;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet`;
public class Zoo {
   private final String name;
   private TreeSet<Cage> cages;
   /* private ArrayList<Cage> cages;*/
   private String Zoo;
   private static Zoo instance = new Zoo();

   public Zoo() {
      this.name = "AnimalK";
   }

   public static Zoo getInstance() {
      if (instance == null)          {
         instance = new Zoo(); 
      }
      return instance; 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see that everything happens in the constructor `Cage()`:

```
public Cage() {
    Zoo z = Zoo.getInstance("ICO41A");
    boolean b = z.addCage(this);
}
```

Note that `z` could be a field if we need to use it later.

Class `Zoo` now: we've seen that getInstance has a `String` argument; I assume it's the name of the `Zoo`, and, instead of a single static instance, we can keep a static `Map<String,Zoo>`:

```
public class Zoo {
   private static Map<String,Zoo> instances = new HashMap<>();

   public static Zoo getInstance(String name) {
      Zoo instance = instances.get(name);
      if (instance == null)          {
         instance = new Zoo(name);
         instances.put(name, instance);
      }
      return instance; 
   }
```

The name is passed to the constructor, and the `Set` `cages` is initialized (with an empty `HashSet`). I've used a `HashSet` instead of a `TreeSet` because `Cage` is not a `Comparable`:

```
   private final String name;
   private final Set<Cage> cages = new HashSet<>();

   private Zoo(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
```

And finally, method `addCage` adds a `Cage` to the set:

```
   public boolean addCage(Cage cage) {
       return cages.add(cage);
   }
```